# simpleopenni point cloud program with Kinect

Tags: processing, kinect, point-clouds

I am trying to use processing to get the point cloud. But it turn out that it does not work

```java
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

import processing.opengl.*;

SimpleOpenNI kinect;

void setup()
{

  size( 1024, 768, OPENGL);

  kinect = new SimpleOpenNI( this );

  kinect.enableDepth();

}

void draw()
{

  background( 0);

  kinect.update();

  translate( width/2,  height/2, -1000);

  rotateX( radians(180));

 stroke(255);

  PVector[] depthPoints = kinect.depthMapRealWorld();

  //the program get stucked in the for loop it loops 307200 times and I don't have any points output

  for( int i = 0; i < depthPoints.length ; i++)
  {

    PVector currentPoint = depthPoints[i];

    point(currentPoint.x,  currentPoint.y, currentPoint.z );
  }

}
```

Comment: there is no errors, I can get the points if i skip 500 pixels(which turn out to be skipping too much) . The first point is working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code if fine, just tested. 
It loops 307200 times because it converts data from the depth image (640x480 = 307200) into 3D positions.

Are you sure you're not getting any errors ? 
Also, drawing all the points in Processing is a bit slow, you might want to skip a few.
And as test, try to print out the 1st point and see if the value changes at all (it should)
or if the depth image has any data (isn't black/filled with zeroes):

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

import processing.opengl.*;

SimpleOpenNI kinect;

void setup()
{

  size( 1024, 768, OPENGL);

  kinect = new SimpleOpenNI( this );

  kinect.enableDepth();

}

void draw()
{

  background( 0);

  kinect.update();
  image(kinect.depthImage(),0,0,160,120);//check depth image

  translate( width/2,  height/2, -1000);

  rotateX( radians(180));

  stroke(255);

  PVector[] depthPoints = kinect.depthMapRealWorld();

  //the program get stucked in the for loop it loops 307200 times and I don't have any points output

  for( int i = 0; i < depthPoints.length ; i+=4)//draw point for every 4th pixel
  {

    PVector currentPoint = depthPoints[i];
    if(i == 0) println(currentPoint);
    point(currentPoint.x,  currentPoint.y, currentPoint.z );
  }

}
```

Comment: there is no errors, I can get the points if i skip 500 pixels(which turn out to be skipping too much) . The first point is working too.

Comment: @xinghua That is odd. Does the depth image look ok (grayscale, not clipped/black/etc.) ? Also, can you successfully run the DepthMap3d sample that comes with SimpleOpenNI ?

Comment: as I said it is too slow to display. The one I get has bad qualities, you can see a bunch of points in lines if you skip a lot of points. However the sample turn out to be perfect.

Comment: then maybe there's something I'm missing in your code...is the same as you posted it ? because what you posted runs just fine on my machine. Anyway, if the sample runs perfect, you can save it as a different sketch, clean it up and carry on from there.

Comment: OK, I will start from there and See what happen. Thank you so much for your help!